# Shaking detection android wear

Tags: android, wear-os

I'm planning to develop an app for Android Wear and I didn't use the sensor before so I need help. My questions:

1. What are the sensors installed with high probability on Android wear? I want to avoid to use sensors mounted only on a few devices;
2. What is the best sensor to detect the shaking? I saw accelerometer but there is even the rotation vector sensor or maybe the gyroscope on x axis? I don't know;
3. Is there any example to how to detect shaking (even on the phone is ok)?
4. Is it possible to detect the movement on the emulator?

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the specs of devices to find out. There's no reason why a wear device should not have an accelerometer, as it's part of the Android API. An LG G has an accelerometer, just google for it.